# Why cant I feed FFServer(Linux) from FFMpeg (Windows)?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

What I want to do is to stream a (only)video file from Windows 10 using RTSP. First, I tried to use webm HTTP instead. I found that ffserver is not avaiable for Windows, so I configured and run ffserver on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04). Then, I downloaded pre-built ffmpeg for Windows x64 and run a ffmpeg command to feed my rtsp server. The fact is that the command didnt work on my Windows machine

The same ffmpeg command works well if I run it in my Linux machine.

The details are descripted below:

ffserver.conf file:

```
HTTPPort 8090                     
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 10000             

CustomLog -
NoDaemon                      

<Feed feed1.ffm>               
   File ./feed1.ffm        
   FileMaxSize 1G           
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.131 #Windows machine IP address
</Feed>

<Stream test.webm>        
   Feed feed1.ffm  
   Format webm

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   VideoSize 720x576    
   VideoFrameRate 25  
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header 

   AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42
   AVOptionVideo quality good
   NoAudio

   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 400         
</Stream>

<Stream status.html> 
   Format status

   ACL allow localhost
   ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
   ACL allow 192.168.0.131 # my windows machine ip
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html> 
   URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

ffmpeg command to feed server:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi http://192.168.0.119:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Error thrown by Windows command line:

```
 Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http://192.168.0.119:8090/feed1.ffm' .
 http://192.168.0.119:8090/feed1.ffm : Invalid argument.
```

Someone told me that Windows newest version of FFMpeg doesnt support ffm, Is that true? I couldnt find a different format example.

Comment: ffserver was recently removed. You'll need an older version of ffmpeg - see https://superuser.com/a/1296382/114058

Comment: Thank you, I dowloaded an older version (binaries) for windows, date jan-2017 and it worked.